# Add currency symbol's as prefix or suffix in IF statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've tried but I can't figure out how to add a prefix of currency symbol when certain conditions are done. For example:
[image]

I want that if I choose "$" and "Paycheck", the result in E2 were $10, and if I choose € in A2, the result were 11€.
I've been trying to achieve that but my code skills are improving very slowly..

Can anyone explain me the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in case you have `€` and `Paycheck` you want to **add** **Price** and **Tax** and this is how 11 is calculated.

Try this in cell **E2**:

```
=if(AND(B2="Paycheck",A2<>""),if(A2="$",C2,C2+D2),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Mario,Thanks for your explanation. However, I'd like to know how to add the symbol of the selected currency in front of the result. Can you do that?

Comment: @markens try something likes this `=if(AND(B2="Paycheck",A2<>""),if(A2="$","$"&C2,to_text(C2+D2)&char(8364)),"")` and let me know if it works

Comment: it didn't made the sum, I changed to `=if(AND(B2="Paycheck",A2<>""),if(A2="$","$"&C2+D2,to_text(C2+D2)),"")` and apparently works. I'll try to figue out how to do the same in case A2 is €. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried the @Mario solution and it worked. However, yours is always adding the tax. Try to copy it his proposal another time